# flink can't reduce the parallelism from 'n' to '1' when recovering through a savepoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

If the program includes operators with window, it is not possible to reduce the parallelism of the operators from n to 1 when restarting from a savepoint, and it will result in an error:

```
IllegalStateException: Failed to rollback to checkpoint/savepoint Checkpoint Metadata. Max parallelism mismatch between checkpoint/savepoint state and new program. Cannot map operator 0e059b9f403cf6f35592ab773c9408d4 with max parallelism 128 to new program with max parallelism 1. This indicates that the program has been changed in a non-compatible way after the checkpoint/savepoint.
```

Comment: You want to be changing the actual parallelism, not the maximum parallelism. How did you specify this configuration?

Comment: @DavidAnderson  parallelism.default,  I don't know why the error message is indicating that the max parallelism has changed，And if I remove the window operator, this issue no longer occurs.

Comment: BTW,Reducing the parallelism to m(m<n&&m>1) is feasible, but reducing it to 1 is not possible.